# Read Exchange Mailboxes in Offline EDB file programmatically

Tags: c#, exchange-server, esent, edb

I've an offline EDB file of exchange server which has around 2 mailboxes and mails inside them. I would like to read them along with mails. I tried searching a lot in the internet, but no where I could get exact information about reading EDB file.

As per my analysis, I've decided to read it using ManagedESENT API (C#). For this, I've got an Open Source http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/ViewESE.html.

Using this I'm able to successfully read the tables and data inside each table. But I cannot map the tables and form a user-viewable structure (Username -> Mailbox -> Categories(Contacts, Inbox, Sent Items etc) -> Items inside category) like many utilities do.

I also tried looking at https://github.com/libyal/libesedb. But it's not very clear & din't get anything out of their code or documentation.

Help me get started !!

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: It will be a challenge. Yes, you can use `ManagedEsent` to access the tables, but everything inside is meant to be efficient for I/O purposes. You may have had better luck with an older version like Exchange 2003, but for 10+ years the Exchange team has been focussed on getting I/O wins, and having an easy-to-understand format was not a priority. Many things get put in to queues (for efficient sequential I/O) and only get evaluated if the user actually uses them (doing the random I/O all at once). (Disclaimer: I used to work in the Exchange team). Third-party tools do a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply !! Can u plz tell me how can i build mail item(subject, body etc) from the table data I have ?.. I'm able to get the body from a column named "NativeBody" in Message_.. folder. But how do i get other properties of the mail item..?